# I need help understanding this piece of code (not familiar with arrow functions)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can somebody please explain to me how this specific piece of code works in the context of a calculator? I'm not familiar with arrow functions. Thank you for your time.

```
function calculate(calc) {
//Perform a calculation expressed as an array of operators and numbers.
var ops = [{'^': (a, b) => Math.pow(a, b)},
           {'*': (a, b) => a * b, '/': (a, b) => a / b},
           {'+': (a, b) => a + b, '-': (a, b) => a - b}],
    newCalc = [],
    currentOp;
```

Comment: That code does not look complete.

Comment: look like ECMA script 6 code

Answer (score 1):

It's a map of arithmetic operations.

So `'^': (a, b) => Math.pow(a, b)` translates to normal function

```
'^': function (a, b) {
    return Math.pow(a, b);
}
```

---

Your code is missing actual call and `ops` structure should be one dimension, not two-dimensional. (`var ops = {'^': ..., '*': ..., '+': ...}`)

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

for example

```
function(a,b){
  //do  something
}
```

is equal to

```
(a,b) => {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: Arrow functions aren't "shortcuts", and differ in several important ways to "normal" functions. [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)